# How to access the master's tableview from detail view in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

A portion of my app has an embedded master-detail section. Each detail view is using a custom `UIViewController`. When I change the value of something inside one of these UIViewControllers I need to be able to grey out one of the table rows in the master `UITableViewController`.

The closest I have seen to a solution is to use `NSNotificationCenter` to bubble up any changes, though this feels a little untidy..

Another solution is to use delegates? But I haven't come across any example solutions or tutorials in how to use this in `Swift`?

I've also experimented just trying to access the table view by navigating back up the hierarchy:

```
   let navController = self.splitViewController!.viewControllers[0];

   navController.tableView.reloadData()
```

I know the example above is wrong, but I don't know how to access the master view that way, or even if it is the right approach.

Oh, I am trying to call `reloadData()` because in the master view there is some logic which checks the condition as to wether to grey out a table row is applicable (i'm using `Core Data`)

Comment: So what is the question? I mean what issue you are facing?

Comment: The question is in the title really. How can I refresh the tableview in the master bit of a UISplitview when an element, for example: a switch, is changed?

Comment: Yes you also mentioned in body that you know how to approach it .So what was the issue you faced when you implement above mentioned code?

Comment: Well, I've identified 3 possible ways to approach it, I'd prefer to do it using navigation properties, I just don't know how to access a parent tableViewController like that i.e navController.parentTableViewController.tableview.reloadata()

Comment: I also do not understand. You got your ViewController correctly, so if that parentTableViewController is public in it, there shouldn't be any problems.

Comment: yeah i figured it out, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I've seen that you figured this one out already. However a cleaner and more future proof way would be to use a delegate protocol:

```
protocol DetailViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func reloadTableView()
}
```

Then add a delegate property to your DetailViewController class and implement the call to the delegate:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: DetailViewControllerDelegate?
    ....

    func reloadMasterTableView() {
        delegate?.reloadTableView()
    }
}
```

And then in your MainViewController implement the delegate method:

```
extension MainViewController: DetailViewControllerDelegate {
    func reloadTableView() {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Don't forget to set the delegate on your DetailViewController instances when you create them:

```
let detailViewController = DetailViewController()
detailViewController.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you use NSNotificationCenter .
If you want to to do it via Navigation controller here is to code should work for you in swift.

```
let navController: UINavigationController = self.splitViewController!.viewControllers[0] as! UINavigationController

let controller: MasterViewController = navController.topViewController as! MasterViewController
controller.tableView.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 2):

Since I was able to access my viewController, I was able to access the parent viewcontroller like so:

```
 func reloadMasterTableView(){
        let navVC: UINavigationController =  self.splitViewController!.viewControllers[0] as! UINavigationController


        let sectionsVC : UIMasterViewController = navVC.topViewController as! UIMasterViewController
        sectionsVC.tableView.reloadData()

    }
```