# SplitView - reload data in master tableView based on detail changed in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail, splitview

I create splitView with tableView in master View and tableView with static cells in two details view (see on picture).
[App Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CstAK.png)

Names of view controllers are:
DocsTableViewController - master view (on the left)
DocDetailTableViewController - detail view (on the top right)
DocEditTableViewControler - second detail view (on the bottom right)

DocsTVC is list of doctors, DocDetailTVC is detail of doctor user selected in DocsTVC and on DocEditTVC user can edit data of doctor showed in DocDetailTVC or add completely new one (based user clicked on edit or add button).

All these things are working fine - show detail, show edit form and save edited or new doc. Problem is the master table view. I'm trying to reload it in detail after saving edited/new item and by `print` I see that data are reload but not the table. Table is showing still the same and I have to go to same other screen of app and then go back to see reloaded table view. What should I do?

After saving doctor on DocEditTVC I'm going back to detail to this method:

```
    @IBAction func saveToDocViewController (segue: UIStoryboardSegue){
    let controller = DocsTableViewController()
    controller.tableView.reloadData()
    print("[SPLIT VIEW] detail: \(controller.docs.count)")
}
```

And some codes from DocsTableViewControler (the master view):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self

    // menu
    if inputsMenuButton != nil {
        inputsMenuButton.target=self.revealViewController()
        inputsMenuButton.action=#selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }

    // navigation bar
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = OAKScolor().colorOAKSmain()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]

    // data load
    print("[SPLIT VIEW]: ViewDidLoad")
    dataLoad()
    self.tableView.reloadData()


    // split view
    self.splitViewController?.delegate = self
    self.splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.AllVisible
}
```

and

```
    func dataLoad() {
    print("[SPLIT VIEW]: DataLoad")
    let arrayOfDocIDs = PlistManager.sharedInstance.getArrayOfValuesFromDict("DocID") as [AnyObject] as! [String]

    for id in arrayOfDocIDs {
        docs.append(DocData(docID: id).docLoad(false))
    }
    print("[SPLIT VIEW] table: \(docs.count)")
}
```

By these `print`s I see that evening is going well - view did load on the master view and array of docs write new count. But the tableView is not changed. Thank you for any help.

Comment: is there any updates on this question ?

Answer (score 0):

With this code

```
let controller = DocsTableViewController()
controller.tableView.reloadData()
```

You created new Master controller instance, not the current one.
There is 2 ways to solve it:

1. In Detail Controller, create a reference to current master controller.
2. Use Delegate. Here is a good explanation:
   https://www.natashatherobot.com/explaining-ios-delegates-a-story-about-your-morning-coffee/#

Hope this help!

Comment: And how can I create reference to current master controller? I tried to implement delegate - i've read article you'd send but it is not in swift. I tried to implement this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33099397/how-to-access-the-masters-tableview-from-detail-view-in-ios) but it doesn't work for me (extension has a problem with `class` and writes error: expected type name in extension declaration).

Comment: Can you post ViewDidLoad function of Master Controller?

Comment: ViewDidLoad function of Master is up in ma Q. At least the part which is relevant for this. The complete function is this too long for comment so I've add it to my Q.

Comment: @martina karbusicka hi, I'm facing the same exact issue. Did I oh figure it out?